# Spivak, Calculus: how to show that $a^x<a^y$ for $a>1$ and $a^x>a^y$ for $a<1$, using the "usual algebraic definition" of $a^x$ for rational $x$.

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, rational-numbers

The following is a problem from Ch. 22 of Spivak's *Calculus*

> 29. Let $a>0$, and for rational $x$ let $f(x)=a^x$, as defined in the usual elementary algebraic way. This problem shows directly that $f$
>     can be extended to a continuous function $\bar{f}$ on the whole line.
>     Problem 28 provided the necessary machinery.
>
> (a) For rational $x<y$, show that $a^x<a^y$ for $a>1$ and $a^x>a^y$ for
> $a<1$.

What is the "usual elementary algebraic way" that $a^x$ is defined for rational $x$?

Here is the solution manual solution to item (a)

> Since $a^y=a^{y-x}\cdot a^x$ we just need that for rational $z$ we
> have $a^z>1$ for $a>1$ and $a^z<1$ for $a<1$, and this follows
> immediately from the elementary definitions.

I don't quite comprehend this solution.

There is a result in Chapter 7 proving that every positive number has an $n^{th}$ root, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and if $n$ is odd then every number has an $n^{th}$ root.

In Chapter 18, we do have a more lengthy discussion about the function $a^x$. Perhaps I am answering my own question here, but it seems the definition of $f(x)=a^x$ for rational $x$ is a function such that

$$a^1=a$$

$$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{Q} \implies f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)=a^{x+y}$$

For this to be true, there are some implicit definitions

- $n\in\mathbb{N}\implies a^n=a\cdot a \cdot a\cdot ...\cdot a$ (n times)
- $a^{-n}=\frac{1}{a^n}$
- $a^{1/n}=\sqrt[n]{a}$
- $a^{m/n}=a^{m/n}=\sqrt[n]{a^m}$

Note that these definitions take care of the cases of a rational $x$ that is either $0$, $-n$, $1/n$, or $m/n$.

Comment: I suspect that the reason they say "the usual elementary way" is partly that you can get the same definition of exponentiation for rational powers in many ways. The way you describe is one, another is that $a^{\frac{n}{m}}$ satisfies $(a^{\frac{n}{m}})^m=a^n$. At least in the case of positive real numbers there are at most two solutions to this (there are two exactly when $m$ is even) and so if we always choose the positive solution we get a definition of $a^x$ for all rational $x$.

Comment: Regarding the solution manual, given this definition it is clear that for $a>1$ we have $a^n>1$ and vice versa (for $n>0$). So (for $m>0$) if $x^m=a^n$ then $x>1$ and so for positive rationals $z$, $a^z>1$ if and only if $a>1$. We can do the same for $a<1$. This proves the result and is sufficiently clear from the definition that I suspect this is what they had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think the definition of $a^x$ for a rational number $x=\frac{q}{p}$, where $q$ is an integer and $p$ is a positive integer in the usual elementary algebraic way is $a^x:=(a^{\frac{1}{p}})^q.$

---

Let $z$ be a positive rational number.
We can write $z=\frac{q}{p}$, where $p$ and $q$ are positive integers.

Let $a>1$.
If $a^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq1,$ then $a=(a^{\frac{1}{p}})^p\leq 1^p=1$.
This is a contradiction.
So, $a^{\frac{1}{p}}>1.$
So, $a^z=(a^{\frac{1}{p}})^q>1^q=1.$

Let $0<a<1$.
If $a^{\frac{1}{p}}\geq 1,$ then $a=(a^{\frac{1}{p}})^p\geq 1^p=1$.
This is a contradiction.
So, $a^{\frac{1}{p}}<1.$
So, $a^z=(a^{\frac{1}{p}})^q<1^q=1.$

---

Let $x,y$ be rational numbers such that $x<y$.
Then, we can write $y=(y-x)+x$.
Since $x<y$, $0<y-x$.
Let $z:=y-x$.
Then, $a^y=a^{(y-x)+x}=a^{y-x}a^{x}=a^za^x.$

If $a>1$, then $a^z>1$ since $z$ is a positive rational number.
So, $a^y=a^za^x>a^x.$

If $0<a<1$, then $a^z<1$ since $z$ is a positive rational number.
So, $a^y=a^za^x<a^x.$